# Animate the background colour of a SKScene

Tags: sprite-kit, skscene, uibackgroundcolor

Is it possible to do this?

Using UIView animations doesn’t work, as expected.

Currently, I’m using about 80 different sprites which animate, which is a big memory issue as well as much more complex to create so many images then import and code them as oppose to just setting the colour in a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `SKSpriteNode` with size of the scene and animate it with `SKAction`s